# How can I force macOS to show the window of a program that I know is open but won't appear anywhere?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, window-manager

My problem arises because sometimes I'm doing something on my MacBook and the user session logs out, as if I'd restarted the computer. Normally it's something exerting that must overload my RAM, like navigating and suddenly opening too many windows (e.g. I was looking for flights and the option was checked to automatically open windows to look in 4 or 5 more different sites).

The thing is, if I have something open like a game, or a half-filled form on Safari I wouldn't wanna lose progress on, like this question... I know that the program stays open because I've been able to still hear the game music and sounds in the background, as if nothing had happened.

So what I was wondering, is if there is a way to force macOS (10.12.5) to forcefully show a window that is not appearing on the dock, mission control or anywhere else.

By the way, the only way I've been able to restart said program, the game for example, has been by terminating the process on the activity monitor. Trying to open it normally doesn't work.

Comment: have you tried clicking on the application icon in the dock. that should bring the apps menus to the menu bar. then from the file menu, you could try open?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using Mission Control?

If the window is indeed open, it should show up there.

**How to use Mission Control:**

- Swipe up with three or four fingers on your Multi-Touch trackpad or Magic Trackpad.
- Double-tap the surface of your Magic Mouse with two fingers.
- Click Mission Control in the Dock or Launchpad.
- Press the Mission Control key on your Apple keyboard, or press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>.
- In OS X El Capitan, drag a window to the top of the screen.

Adapted from [Apple's Support Page](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204100).